# Angular 7 nested for using parent value as index for child

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, nested-loops, ngfor

Is it possible to do this in Angular 2+?

let's say I have the following objects:

```
 myParent = [{id: 1, code: 'code1', title: 'parentTitle1'}, {id: 2, code: 'code2', title: 'parentTitle2'}];
 myChild = {code1: [{id: 1, title: 'childTitle1'}, {id: 2, title: 'childTitle2'}], code2: [{id: 4, title: 'childTitle1'}]
```

I wanna Iterate the first one and then display the items of the second one, using the 'code' value of the parent object as index:

```
<h3 *ngFor="let parent of myParent">{{parent .title}} 
  <br>
  <span *ngFor="let child of myChild[parent.code]"> {{child.title}} </span>
  <br>
</h3>
```

I'm not getting any error on the console, but the child 'for' is not displaying anything. I used to do this on AngularJS but not sure if it's possible to do it in NG7

Comment: `myChild` is an object.... you cannot iterate over objects

Comment: @Nickolaus the iteration is not over myChild but over myChild propery code which is an array

Comment: right... but.... `myChild = {code1: [{id: 1, title: childTitle1}`.... childTitle1 is not a string ;) ...

Comment: It's an attribute

Comment: no `title` is the attribute therfore it should be `title: 'childTitle1'`

Comment: It was a typo, in the actual code is a string. I just edited the snippet, and the array can be iterated, I did it in a single ngFor and it worked

Comment: Check the stackblitz. The properties of the object can be accessed as an array key.

Comment: Yup, saw it, but for some reason is not working on my environment, I'll try some more debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvvo5k?file=src/app/app.component.html). Is this not working for you?

I tried with these data:

```
  myParent = [{id: 1, code: 'code1', title: 'parentTitle1'}, {id: 2, code: 'code2', title: 'parentTitle2'}];
 myChild = {code1: [{id: 1, title: 'childTitle1'}, {id: 2, title: 'childTitle2'}], code2: [{id: 4, title: 'childTitle1'}]};
```

And the html

```
<h3 *ngFor="let parent of myParent">{{parent .title}} 
  <br>
  <span *ngFor="let child of myChild[parent.code]"> {{child.title}} </span>
  <br>

</h3>
```

The stackblitz is working as you intended. Can you share some more code, as it seems like the data might not match.

Comment: OK, I figured out why the downvote. Can you check again please?

Comment: Maybe you could add relevent part of the stackblitz to your answer, it will greatly improve it's quality.

Comment: I didn't because my only fix was to make the titles as strings which was not really the problem in this case.

Comment: Your answer is correct, I double checked the code and there was a method doing a deep clone of the original object that was faulty, I was logging the wrong array, so, my mistake!
Thanks!